# Error importing namespace into XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm getting this error when I try to import a particular namespace to my custom user control. The line causing this error is the import: 'xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Wifi.Toolbar'. If I remove this line the error disappears.

WifiCollaborateToolbarView.xaml(1,1): error MC3000: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.' XML is not valid.

Windows 7
Visual Studio 2010 SP1
.NET 4.0

Here is the XAML file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wifi.Toolbar.WifiCollaborateToolbarView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Wifi.Toolbar">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="CollaborateStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="GridTopLevel" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <c:CollaborateButton x:Name="ButtonName"
                             Grid.Column="0" 
                             Style="{StaticResource MpCollaborateButtonStyle}"/>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the class that I am trying to import into this file. It exists in the same assembly as the XAML file.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Wifi.Toolbar
{
    [TemplatePart(Name="PART_Icon", Type=typeof(Image))]
    [TemplatePart(Name="PART_Caption", Type=typeof(TextBlock))]
    public class CollaborateButton : Button
    {
        private Image part_icon;
        private TextBlock part_caption;

        public CollaborateButton()
        {

        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            ...
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            ...
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            ...            
        }
    }   
}
```

The button Template

```
<Style x:Key="MpCollaborateButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type c:CollaborateButton}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MpCollaborateButtonNormalStrokeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MpButtonNormalFillBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                        <Grid Margin="6,0,12,0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image x:Name="PART_Icon"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Margin="0,0,7,0" 
                                   Width="16" 
                                   Height="16" 
                                   Source="Images/Collaboration_MeetingName_16x16.png" />

                            <TextBlock x:Name="PART_Caption"
                                       Grid.Column="2"
                                       Text="This is some really long text that is only for testing purposes. Isn't this fun?"
                                       Style="{StaticResource MpCollaborateTextBlock}"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MpButtonDownFillBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: did you try to replace shortcut `c` with some other one? (maybe it's somehow reserved)

Comment: Yes I did - I should have mentioned that. I tried shortcuts that I've used successfully in the past.

Comment: Where is the Xaml of your Toolbar?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code from here into a test project and it works fine for me. Anyways, XML is not valid errors are usually due to bad xml formatting (missing a > symbol for example)

Comment: @Silvermind I'm not sure which XAML you're asking about. The XAML for the toolbar is posted, that's the user control. I can post the template I'm applying to the CollaborateButton if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: @HighCore I'll try creating an entirely new project and report back if that solves the problem.

Comment: @HighCore - Creating a new project seems to have solved the problem. I would love to know what actually went wrong though. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Look for a file called `Generic.xaml` probably in a folder named `Themes`. When you create a custom control like the toolbar, xaml is automatically added to that file. That was the xaml that was broken and that was the xaml I meant. ;) Correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: @Silvermind - I didn't create a Generic.xaml. I only wrote the style that I added to my post above. This style works now that I've created a new project and re-added the various elements.

Comment: I meant the `Button`-Template of course, but it's already there.

Comment: Weird issue, glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You must have had some junk before your root level UserControl declaration. Maybe it was tabbed over where you didn't see it. For example, this would cause the error in question...

```
                                                                                                      Junk
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Which is the same as this:

```
Junk
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: That was my thought too, but I actually opened the file in a hex editor and confirmed that there were no miscellaneous characters.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I had this same error, and in my case it was because there was an extra empty line after the closing `</UserControl>` tag (This likely happened as a result of someone copying and pasting an entire xaml file). Removing that line got rid of the error.